# Accelerometer outputs vs the real accelerations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration

TL, DR : the long sentence in bold.

I have been reasearching about accelerometers for a while, and I saw many times the following sentence:

Accelerometers don't sense gravity, they sense every other accelerations other than gravitational acceleration.

Is this statement fully correct?

During a free-fall there exists an acceleration due to the gravitational force acting on it(excluding other forces, i.e in vacuum) on the body right?(Correct me if I am wrong)

A body sitting on a flat surface and not moving should have a **0** acceleration (the forces on it are gravitational force and normal force equal in magnitude but with reverse directions, thus cancelling each other), right?(Correct me if I am wrong)

I think both my 2 statements above are correct, However;

I have a 3-axes accelerometer and when it is standing on a flat surface (table for ex.), xy plane is level with the horizon and **positive** z axis points towards the sky, accelerometer outputs a **+ 1g** in z axis. And when the sensor is in free-fall(xy plane is still horizontal,i.e level) it outputs **0 g** in z axis again.

So these two observations conflicts with two *realities*. **Then should I conclude that, accelerometers indeed don't sense gravity (explains why free-fall results in a 0 g output) and for the case it is standing on a table it senses the acceleration due to the normal force?**

P.s : When applying a force towards +/- x or +/- y, the outputs are consistent with how they have to be physically.

I asked other questions somehow similar to this on different communities (electronics, aviation, robotics etc.) but also wanted to get some answers from the perspective of physics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's an accelerometer exactly measuring?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315813/)

Comment: Given that part of testing accelerometers with ~few g range is to use earth’s gravitational field (and flip up/down), you appear to have a flawed view of their capabilities.

Comment: @AaronStevens I actually saw quite a number of questions similar to mine before posting this one but never seen the one you shared before, I did not read it fully to know whether it answers my question but it looks promising. Thanks for pointing out and sorry if it is really a one-to-one duplicate.

Comment: No need to apologize

Comment: One way of describing what a scale measures is, it measures the _contact force_ between the object being weighed and the surface of the Earth that stops the object from following the path that gravity and inertia want it to follow. Consider that the only difference between a scale and a 1-D accelerometer are (a) the test mass is unknown in the case of the scale, but it is known for the accelerometer, and (b) the scale normally is operated at a fixed location so that it won't be affected by inertia, whereas with the accelerometer, measuring the inertial forces usually is the whole point.

Comment: @SolomonSlow a helpful analogy, thanks!